# Div with border resizes on dragend

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I've got a container with a couple of draggable and resizable blocks. Because I want to be able to show the user which block is 'active' I add the class `active` to it which adds a border.

Now the issue is when I drag the block and drop it in the container a couple of times the div gets bigger and bigger. Which of course isn't really practical.

When I remove the styling from the `active` class this doesn't happen so this has to do with the border that is being added. This class gets removed from all blocks when a block is selected.

Note that it's important that both `width` and `height` must be set for this project.

I've created a little demo and added a Fiddle which shows the issue.
[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/te2b2uhj/)

Just drag one of the blocks a couple of times. Can someone explain to me why this is happening and how to resolve it?

Comment: Just add this line of code at the begining of `setDimensions` : `$(obj).removeClass('active');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Titus stated the problem was that the `height` and `width` were incorrectly calculated on the drop where it also added the `width` of the `border`.

Since it's important that  both `width` and `height` need to be set for this project on these elements I used jQuerys `innerWidth()` and `innerHeight()` functions to calculate the `width` and `height` of the element without border.

Since there is a border I also need to remove this number in the calculation. The code below solved my problem.

```
function setDimensions(obj) {  
    obj.css('position', 'absolute');
    obj.css("left",parseInt(obj.css("left")) / ($container.width() / 100)+"%");
    obj.css("top",parseInt(obj.css("top")) / ($container.height() / 100)+"%");  
    obj.width(((obj.innerWidth() - obj.css('borderWidth')) / $container.width()) * 100 + '%');
    obj.height(((obj.innerHeight() - obj.css('borderWidth')) / $container.height()) * 100 + '%');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't set `width` and `height` on drop:

```
function setDimensions(obj) {

    obj.css('position', 'absolute');
    obj.css("left",parseInt(obj.css("left")) / ($container.width() / 100)+"%");
    obj.css("top",parseInt(obj.css("top")) / ($container.height() / 100)+"%");  
    //obj.width((obj.width() / $container.width()) * 100 + '%');
    //obj.height((obj.height() / $container.height()) * 100 + '%');
  }
```

[Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9bdewkp9/)

Just so you know, you have another problem where if you resize a block, both the `width` and `height` change also. You'll probably want to save the initial `width` and `height` of the block using `resizable`'s `start()` function, then compare those sizes to the end sizes in the `stop()` function and only update either the `width` or the `height`.

(Unless, of course, that resize is intended behavior)

Comment: Thanks for your tip on the resizing. Regarding the drop, I forgot to mention in the question that setting the `width` and `height` is important. I figured it out by using `innerWidth()` and `innerHeight()` to calculate the correct size. Besides that +1 for your answer.